# solr user Interface

Tags: user-interface, solr, lucene

**Hi everyone**

I am  noob with **Solr/Lucene**.
I want a tutorial or book about how to make simple **UI** (user interface) for talking to Solr/Lucene Apache, or simple user interface even better.
I prefer to create user interface using Java script , html, and all these on Apache tomcat.

**thanks**

Comment: You should mention the programming language, at the least. And Solr has an easy REST (XML/JSON/others over HTTP) interface so its simple to create an interface.

Comment: See ajax-solr: https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with - Indexing data using [Tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/doc-files/tutorial.html)

The example comes up with the nice simple interface based on [Velocity](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter) & JQuery, which can be customized further. (Check for the browse request handler)
You can also you [XSLT](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter) to creating custom UI designs.

A lot of clients are available with Solr to help you design interfaces in languages like Solrj for Java, rsolr & sunspot for Ruby etc.

For a book you can check for [LucidWorks for Solr Reference Guide](http://www.lucidimagination.com/downloads).
Its free to download and can get you started with the basics (However it may not provide you with the UI designing)